# Xamarin Worklight sample compile error

Tags: xamarin, ibm-mobilefirst

I downloaded the sample Xamarin Worklight sample project and tried to compile it on Xamarin Studio but I a compiler error that I'm not able to fix. Is there something that I'm missing here ? Can anyone please help?

Here is the error message -

**File not found: U:\Android\WorklightSample\Android\COMPILETODALVIK**

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a Xamarin IDE issue.

See the following  Xamarin Forum post: [Urgent: Xamarin.Forms.Maps does not build -> COMPILETODALVIK : UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21744/urgent-xamarin-forms-maps-does-not-build-compiletodalvik-unexpected-top-level), for more details and a possible solution.

Specifically, the solution provided by jeff.albano to increase the `Java Max Heap Size` in `Android Options -> Andvanced Tab` as well as verify the manifest settings per the given example.

Comment: If it was a Xamarin issue, none of the Android projects should work. In this case, only the Worklight project gives error.